# Windows network adapter lease expiration makes connection drop

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp

I've been noticing that the connection is dropping for a few seconds in a Windows 2016 instance hosted on AWS.

Now, I've found that it drops when the Lease expires. It's expiring every hour and that's making all the connections drop. Because it's hosting a SQL Server, it's very problematic.

How can I extend the lease time or make it continue working when it gets renewed?  It's configured to use DHCP and I don't see any non-default configuration. Firewall and IPSec is enabled if it matters.

[image: network adapter lease expiration]

**UPDATE:**

After the lease expired, I've noticed that the IPv6 was changed. Since it's renewing only the IPv6 address and I don't need it, I will disable IPv6 to fix it. Even if it fixes the problem, it still sounds pretty bad.

**UPDATE 2:**

Setting the IP to static fixes the problem, but of course that's just a workaround, not a real solution as some might need DHCP. I'll wait for an answer that solves the problem without a workaround.

Comment: See here, I haven't seen this issue personally. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=247387

Comment: @Appleoddity thanks. I've already have the server set in UTC and some quote Microsoft recommendation to leave that setting to zero. So not sure what to do.

Comment: If fixed, please post it as an answer, you can mark your own without problem

Comment: @yagmoth555 for now I've set the IP to static, but that's not a solution I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution after a while. I had IPSec configured encrypting all the communication in the network. The solution was to allow UDP connections to the DCHP server with encrypting them.